# Facebook Graph API add extra parameter to login url

Tags: facebook-graph-api

is there any way to get back my users to the current page after they login and redirect to my callback url? for example my current page url is:

```
https://mydomain.test/post1
```

then my callback url is:

```
https:/mydomain.test/callback.php
```

I tried to add extra parameter to login url but got an error because of the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs url match. my url is dynamic so I need a way to set parameters that changes and start from there.

Comment: Set something in a session/cookie. Read that value and redirect from the callback.

Comment: Or, alternatively, make it part of the `state` parameter (which is exempt from the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs restriction.) Since that also serves CSRF protection purposes, you should not make it a purely static value though - but combining for example a random value and the data you need to transport into a JSON string would be a possibility.

Comment: can you give an example of how to do it? I tried the state parameter but still doesn't work.